# Feather icon not displayed after using react-bootstrap-carousel

Tags: reactjs, icons, carousel, feather

I am working on the react js project. I am using the feather icon in my project. It works fine before I used the **react-bootstrap-carousel** in my project.

**Image before using react-bootstrap-carousal on project**

[image: Image before using react boostrap carousal on project]

I import the following

```
import RBCarousel from "react-bootstrap-carousel";
import "react-bootstrap-carousel/dist/react-bootstrap-carousel.css";
```

after importing this I got the error

**Image after using react-bootstrap-carousal on Project**

[image: Image after using react-bootstrap-carousal on project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before{
    font-family:inherit !important;
}
```

put and try this style in your project